# QStringList (and others) not found while linking Qt using cmake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I'll start off by mentioning that I'm trying to integrate Qt into a much larger project, and I'm forced to use cmake (so no qmake, unfortunately). I'm also really inexperienced with cmake, so I might be doing something horribly wrong.

I do the following things:

```
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/opt/Qt/5.10.1/gcc_64")
set(Qt5_DIR "/opt/Qt/5.10.1/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5")

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Widgets Gui REQUIRED)

add_executable(stride sim/main.cpp)
target_include_directories(stride PUBLIC SYSTEM
    ${CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY}/main/resources/lib/tclap/include
    /opt/Qt/5.10.1/gcc_64/include)
target_link_libraries(stride ${LIBS} libstride Qt5::Core Qt5::Widgets)
install(TARGETS stride  DESTINATION   ${BIN_INSTALL_LOCATION})
```

However in one of the files I'm trying to compile, I still get

```
QStringList: No such file or directory
```

It's the first file that includes a Qt header, so I'm guessing it would say this for all following files too.

Comment: You did not set your include directories for Qt in your non-standard location.

Comment: You may need to actually include the Qt include directories. For example, `include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})`.

Comment: That solved it, thanks.
Having trouble with qt5_wrap_ui now.